# drawable not working properly (rendering issue)

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't fetch icon into drawable-hdpi folder, outside icon working correctly,but hdpi,xxdpi,mdpi icon can't fetch.

Here is the error image [image: link]

Comment: Just put all the folders outside drawable directory it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use android:src="@drawable/image_name"

Comment: sOME technical iscue bro

Answer (score 0):

You `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi` and `drawable-xxxhdpi` directories should be outside your `drawable` directory, directly hanging from your `res` directory

Comment: wait.. now again rendering issue accured, it says Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/ic_add_black  Failed to convert @drawable/ic_add_black into a drawable

Comment: Maybe your png has some problem. Can you open your `ic_add_black.png` with an image application?

Comment: i converted this image in this link:   https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=11&padding=3&color=000%2C100&name=ic_add_black